# Custom Icon in gtk toggle_action

Tags: python, gtk

I have the following code which adds a toolbar icon "gtk-info" (from stock) to a python Gtk+ window. I would like to have a custom icon instead. How would I do that?

```
    self.action = ('ActivateSqueezeboxMode','gtk-info', _('SqueezeboxTools'),
                    None, _('Activate Squeezebox mode'),
                    self.activate_button_press, True)
    self.action_group = gtk.ActionGroup('SqueezeboxPluginActions')
    self.action_group.add_toggle_actions([self.action])
    uim = self.shell.get_ui_manager()
    uim.insert_action_group (self.action_group, 0)
    self.ui_id = uim.add_ui_from_string(context_ui)
    uim.ensure_update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.action = ('ActivateSqueezeboxMode', None, _('SqueezeboxTools'),
                None, _('Activate Squeezebox mode'),
                self.activate_button_press, True)
self.action_group = gtk.ActionGroup('SqueezeboxPluginActions')
self.action_group.add_toggle_actions([self.action])
# now get your action back out of the action group so you can modify it
action = self.action_group.get_action('ActivateSqueezeboxMode')
action.set_icon_name('my-custom-icon')
```

to use a named icon, or

```
action.set_gicon(my_custom_gicon)
```

as the last line to use a `gio.Icon` (see for example [`gio.FileIcon`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/class-giofileicon.html).)

Comment: cool!! it works!! I can only +1 and accept but I am very grateful! Thanks!